# Let $F[[X]]$ be the ring of formal power series over the field $F$. Show that $(X)$ is a maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, formal-power-series

I need to prove the following:

Let $F[[X]]$ be the ring of formal power series over the field $F$. Show that $(X)$ is a maximal ideal.

I think I can prove this in three different ways

(1) $(X$) is a maximal ideal if and only if $F[[X]]/(X)$ is a field

(2) We can show that $(X)$ is a prime ideal since prime ideals are maximal.

(3) We can assume that $(X)$ is not maximal and get a contradiction.
This is my attempt for (1), which I think is not complete:

Let $(X) = \{\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}a_iX^i: a_i \in F \}$ (all elements whose constant term is zero).

We can show that $F[[X]]/(X) \cong F$ and that would imply that $F[[X]]/(X)$ is also a field.

We have that

$$F[[X]]/(X) = \{ f + (X): f \in F[[X]] \mbox { and the constant term of } f  \mbox{ is not zero } \} $$

Hence, for any element $p \in F[[X]]/(X)$,

$$p = a_0 + a_1X^1 + a_2X^2 + ... + b_1X^1 + b_2X^2 + ...  $$
$$p = a_0 + (a_1 + b_1)X^1 + (a_2 + b_2)X^2 + ...$$

Then required isomorphism $\phi: F[[X]]/(X) \to F$, is given by

$$ \phi(p) = a_0 \in F$$

I must show that for any $p,q \in F[[X]]/(X)$,

(1) $\phi(pq) = \phi(p)\phi(q)$

(2) $\phi(p + q) = \phi(a) + \phi(b)$

(3) $\phi(1_{F[[X]]/(X)}) = 1_F = 0$

Now since $p,q \in F[[x]]/(X)$,

$$p = a_0 + (a_1 + b_1)X^1 + (a_2 + b_2)X^2 + ... = p_0 + p_1X^1 + p_2X^2 + ...$$
$$q = c_0 + (c_1 + d_1)X^1 + (c_2 + d_2)X^2 + ... = q_0 + q_1X^1 + q_2X^2 + ...$$

Now by the Cauchy product, we have that

$$pq = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}c_nX^n$$

where $c_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}p_iq_{n-i}$, therefore

$$ \phi(pq) = c_0 = p_0q_0 = a_0c_0 = \phi(p)\phi(q) $$

Also,

$$ \phi(p + q) = p_0 + a_0 = a_0 + c_0 = \phi(p) + \phi(q) $$

Now $1_{F[[X]]/(X)} = 0 + (X)$, hence

$$\phi(0 + (X)) = 0 = 1_F$$

$$\therefore \phi \mbox{ is a ring (field) isomorphism.} $$

$$\therefore F[[X]]/(X) \cong F, \therefore F[[X]]/(X) \mbox{ is a field since F is.}$$

$$\therefore(X) \mbox{ is a maximal ideal. } \square $$

Can anyone verify my proof for part (1), and help me with part (2) or (3) ?

I think my approach is very long and uses an important result. I want to prove it in a more direct way.

Comment: The one in the ring $F[[X]]/(X)$ with respect to multiplication of residue classes of formal power series is $1+(X)$ and not $0+(X)$, otherwise your mapping $\phi:F[[X]]/(X)\rightarrow F$ wouldnt be a ring homomorphism between rings with one at all, but it is and this is the easiest way to show that $(X)$ is maximal.

Comment: $(x)$ is maximal if and only if $x$ is irreducible which is easier to show. Indeed, if $x = f(x)g(x)$ then $1 = \mathrm{deg}(x) = \mathrm{deg}(f(x))+\mathrm{deg}(g(x))$. In particular, one of $f$ and $g$ has zero degree and must be a unit in $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @PeterMelech that is a point that always confuses me. Since fields are rings, with multiplicative inverses and it has two operations attached, from the definition is never clear for me which of the identities they are talking about. Why  is 1 and not 0 ?

Comment: For (2), why is prime ideal maximal?

Comment: Maximal ideals are prime.  Prime ideals are not necessarily maximal.  For example, in the ring $k[x.y]$, $(x)$ is prime but not maximal.

Comment: @Aaron thanks for that clarification. I was thinking it was an equivalence.

Comment: @RichardClare Sure, on a ring $F$ that is a field there are two operations but You obtain a group structure with respect to just one of these operations, call it $+:F\times F \rightarrow F$ and to obtain a group structure with the other one call it $.:F\times F\rightarrow F$ You have to take out the identitiy element with respect to the other operation. In the case of a field You have thus two group structures: $(F,+)$ and  $(F\backslash \{0\},.)$ where $0$ is the identity element with respact to $+$.The identitity element of this last group is $1$!

Comment: @PeterMelech very nice! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Once one sees that

$(X) = \displaystyle \left \{ \sum_1^\infty a_i X^i \mid \forall i \; a_i \in F  \right \}, \tag 1$

that is, the principal ideal $(X)$ consists of all those formal power series in $X$ such that the constant term $a_0 = 0 \in F$, then showing $(X)$ is maximal is basically a one-liner.

To see that (1) binds, we first observe that

$\displaystyle \left \{ \sum_1^\infty a_i X^i \mid \forall i \; a_i \in F  \right \} \subset (X), \tag 2$

since any element of $\{ \sum_1^\infty a_i X^i \mid \forall i \; a_i \in F \}$ satisfies

$\displaystyle  \sum_1^\infty a_i X^i = X  \sum_1^\infty a_iX^{i - 1} \in (X), \tag 3$

and we also have, for

$b(X) = \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty b_i X^i \in F[[X]], \tag 4$

$Xb(X) = \displaystyle X \sum_0^\infty b_i X^i =  \sum_0^\infty b_i X^{i + 1} = \sum_1^\infty b_{i - 1} X^i \in  \left \{ \sum_1^\infty a_i X^i \mid \forall i \; a_i \in F \right \}, \tag 5$

which shows that

$(X) \subset \displaystyle \left \{ \sum_1^\infty a_i X^i \mid \forall i \; a_i \in F  \right \}; \tag 6$

(2) and (6) together imply (1).

With this little result in hand, the promised one-liner goes as follows:

Suppose

$M \supsetneq (X) \tag 7$

is an ideal *properly* containing $(X)$; since it is clear from (1) that $(X)$ consists *precisely* of those elements of $F[[X]]$ whose zero-degree term is $0 \in F$, $M$ must contain at least one formal power series of the form

$c(X) =  \displaystyle \sum_0^\infty c_i X^i, \; c_0 \ne 0; \tag 8$

but it is clear from (1) that

$ \displaystyle \sum_1^\infty c_i X^i \in (X) \subset M \tag 9$

and thus, since $M$ is an ideal,

$c_0 = c(X) - \displaystyle \sum_1^\infty c_i X^i \in M; \tag{10}$

but $c_0 \ne 0 \in F$ is a unit; thus

$1 = c_0^{-1} c_0 \in M, \tag{11}$

which of course implies for any $a(X) \in F[[X]]$,

$a(X) = 1a(X) \in M; \tag{12}$

thus

$M = F[[X]], \tag{13}$

and so $(X)$ must be maximal.

Comment: I will read it carefully tomorrow to accept this as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you my friend!  I may add a few more remarks.  Cheers!